# Error in vue js, problems with v-show or v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Good morning people, I'm going to comment on my mistake. This is a users screen. Where I have a record and an edit. Register is with id 0 and edit i have id types. My idea was, when you enter the registrar, you will see the change password fields (so far everything is perfect.). The issue is on the edit screen, my idea is until I select the role, the password fields did not appear. Once you choose the role, you can change your password.
Then I have the select, of roles. That the idea would be to bring me the role. And it doesn't. It takes me the text-field, but in the v-select it doesn't bring me the value. Attached images below.

v-select error does not bring me the data.

[image]
[image]
The roles are shown to me, but I would like it to be put in the select, as in the text fields. is there any way?
And there once the role is selected. The idea would be that the password fields appear. If there is no role selected, it should not appear.

```
 <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>
          <v-select
            label="Rol"
            v-model="form.rolId"
            :items="roles"
            item-value="value"
            item-text="text"
            :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Este campo es requiredo']"
            required
          ></v-select>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="form.password"
            v-show="showPassword"
            :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Este campo es requiredo']"
            :type="'password'"
            label="Contraseña"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="form.confirmPassword"
            v-show="showPassword"
            :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Este campo es requiredo']"
            :type="'password'"
            label="Confirmar contraseña"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-row class="text-center">
            <v-col cols="12" lg="3">
              <v-btn
                block
                class="mr-4 blue white--text rounded-lg"
                @click="submit"
                submit
                >Guardar</v-btn
              >
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-form>

 data() {
return {
  form: {},
  showPassword: true,
  roles: [
    { value: "Agente", text: "Agente" },
    { value: "Administrador", text: "Administrador" },
  ],
};
```

},

```
 getOne(id) {
  if (id != "0") {
    this.showPassword = false;
    this.usuarioServices
      .getOne(id)
      .then((data) => {
        this.form = data;
        this.form.password = "Encripted";
        this.form.confirmPassword = "Encripted";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.status);
      });
  }
},
submit() {
  if (this.form.password != this.form.confirmPassword) {
    this.showError("Las contraseñas no coinciden.");
    return;
  }
  this.$refs.form.validate();
  if (this.$refs.form.validate(true)) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Espere unos momentos ...",
      showConfirmButton: false,
    });
    if (this.form.id == "0") {
      this.usuarioServices
        .registrar(this.form)
        .then((data) => {
          Swal.close();
          if (data == "") {
            this.$router.push({ path: "/usuarios/listar" });
            this.showSuccess("Entro al sistema correctamente.");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          Swal.close();
          if (error.response.status == 401) {
            this.showError("El mail o password es invalido.");
          } else {
            this.showError(error.response.data);
          }
          console.log(error.response.status);
        });
    } else {
      this.usuarioServices
        .editar(this.form)
        .then((data) => {
          Swal.close();
          if (data == "") {
            this.$router.push({ path: "/usuarios/listar" });
            this.showSuccess("Entro al sistema correctamente.");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          Swal.close();
          if (error.response.status == 401) {
            this.showError("El mail o password es invalido.");
          } else {
            this.showError(error.response.data);
          }
          console.log(error.response.status);
        });
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: It is select only as per the screenshot you put in the post. and on select the correct role you can just show/hide the password text fields.

Comment: Yes, but how? I've been trying various ways, and all it does is display it. But when I go into edit, I want it to hide everything again.

Comment: can you please create a small reproduceable example using `jsfiddle` or `codepen` so that I can look into that.

Comment: Instead of `v-show="showPassword"`. You can simply do `v-show="form.rolId"` in both the password text fields. As `form.rolld` is containing the selected role value. Hence, if it will be falsy .. textfields will not be shown

Comment: ooh!! There I fixed it and I'm fine.. The last thing I have left is to see the theme of the select.
Because when it enters the edit screen, it would have to bring me the role that it has in the database. When I do the console.log() it shows me the role, but it does not place it

Comment: In that case the role you are getting from the database should match with the value of the options you have in the select. So that it can be automatically selected on edit.

Comment: Rohit Here I share this link so you can see better what I tell you, it has the code you asked me for and images of the error.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205387/problems-with-v-select-and-data

Comment: Why did you created separate question for that. You can edit that in this same question. I will check and add my answer by tomorrow morning. As here in india it's late night

Comment: Oh, I didn't know, sorry. Great, I look forward to your response. Thank you very much friend.

Comment: I added an answer as per the problems you are facing. Please have a look and let me know if still any challenges you are facing

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you are facing two challenges in your code **:**

*1. How to hide/show password text fields based on the role select by the user ?*

Instead of `v-show="showPassword"`, You can simply do `v-show="form.rolId"` in both the password text fields. As `form.rolld` is containing the selected role value. Hence, if it will be `falsy` (empty/null/undefined) .. text fields will not be shown.

*2. How to display/show existing role (which coming from database) in the select box when user is on edit page ?*

I can see, API returning `roles` as an array `['Agente']`. Hence, while binding the value to `v-model` in the `<v-select>`. It should be access via zero index `apiResponse.roles[0]`.