# Problems with v-select and data

Tags: node.js, vue.js, select, vue-component, vuetify.js

Good afternoon friends, then I'm going to tell you my mistake. I am working for a users screen, where you have your registration and editing. When you enter the register section you don't have to show the role you already have in the database. But on the edit screen, it already has a role assigned, so I would have to bring it to it (as it does with the text-fields) But I can't get it to load them.
attached images of the screen:
[image]
[image]

When I do a debugger as soon as I enter the screen, I realize that it is returning the roles as an array. And it shows me the role well, but it doesn't place it in the select.
Attached image of the error, below the images is the code that I use.
[image]

```
 <v-select
            label="Rol"
            v-model="form.rolId"
            :items="roles"
            item-value="value"
            item-text="text"
            :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Este campo es requiredo']"
            required
          >
          </v-select>

 data() {
return {
  form: {},
  roles: [
    { value: "Agente", text: "Agente" },
    { value: "Administrador", text: "Administrador" },
  ],
};
```

},

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a default value on your v-model for it to load the data in the select.

[see codepen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWb9I.png)